# ubuntu software center installation?

Tags: software-center, package-management

hello i am new to ubuntu and i have been trying to download wine, mp3 media players readers, and VLC. However every single time i try to download something this message pops p and closes the download it is really ennoying as ubuntu is useless without this working properly =( here is the message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1) but 2.0.5-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 6:0.8.4) but 6:0.8.5ubuntu0.12.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 6:0.8.4) but 6:0.8.5ubuntu0.12.10.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu20.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.10-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13 is to be installed
```

i really need help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a problem of missing dependencies, try updating your ubuntu first. Or the program needs the latest version of ubuntu. Which version do you use?

Comment: ubuntu 12.10 their are no updates available it says =(

Comment: but what do you mean by dependencies? and if they do miss were can i get it?

Comment: try this in the terminal: sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Enter them one line at a time. After opening terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T

Answer (score 0):

Try:

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get update

check this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Regards.

Comment: it doesnt work =// thx for helping